# Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start activity

Tags: android, kotlin, manifest, runtimeexception

This crash from play console on android 11
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.innogenius.easy.photo.compress/com.example.imageresizer.ui.activities.MainActivity}: androidx.fragment.app.y: Unable to instantiate fragment j5.g: could not find Fragment constructor

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.innogenius.easy.photo.compress/com.example.imageresizer.ui.activities.MainActivity}: androidx.fragment.app.y: Unable to instantiate fragment j5.g: could not find Fragment constructor
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3420)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3559)
android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:140)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:96)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2092)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:264)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7593)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:980)
```

i try change code in manifest